# How can I get timezone of a specific country?

Tags: windows-phone-7, timezone

How can I get the timezone of a specific city/country, I have the latitude and the longitude of the country. Can I do that with the `TimeZoneInfo` class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't do it with `TimeZoneInfo` as far as I'm aware.

The [Geonames](http://www.geonames.org/export/web-services.html#timezone) web service will give you the time zone, but it will give you the zoneinfo name rather than the Windows ID. You could use the [CLDR](http://cldr.unicode.org/) information to provide a mapping between the two of them - that's what we do for [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com). (You'd embed the mapping information into your app; it's reasonably straightforward.) It looks like you can also download the Geonames data, but I expect you'd have a fair amount of work to do to use it on the device.

Of course if you'd be interested in using Noda Time directly, I'd be happy to hear about your requirements. It's not quite hit production yet, but the more use cases we have, the quicker we'll be able to design the API appropriately :)

Comment: i think the first link (the geonames webservice) is more than enough, thanks, but i still wonder if theres another way, without using a web service

Comment: @user836252: As I said, you can download the data from Geonames yourself - but you'll need to work out how to use it from C#.